# Possessive form for words ending in "y"

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

Which of the following is correct?

> The fortune 500 companys' assets are vast.
>
> The fortune 500 companies' assets are vast.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think this would clear things up:

- This Fortune 500 company
- This Fortune 500 company’s assets are vast
- These Fortune 500 companies
- These Fortune 500 companies’ assets are vast

Even though it’s possessive, it’s still pluralized in the normal way for nouns ending in -y.