# Should it be "find your company's zen"?

Tags: apostrophe

Should it be "find your company's zen" or "find your companys' zen"? Or perhaps another?

I am convinced it should be "find your company's zen" as it suggests ownership of said zen, but I want to be sure.

What should it be?

Comment: Interesting question. It's not, by necessity: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/838/possessive-form-for-words-ending-in-y is it.

The problem I'm having with it is I would like to see either:

The company zen

...meaning the zen of the company, or the possessive from the first example i.e., 'company's zen'.

Comment: It should either be "company's" or "company".  The former treats "company" as a corporation, the latter as a group of people you work with.

Comment: There is no construction where *companys'* would be correct. The possessive of a singular unit is *company's*; the plural, *companies'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form should be:

"Find your company's zen."

"Companys' zen," is wrong as it suggests a plural, which in any case is the incorrect declension. The plural of company is companies. If you had wanted to suggest more than one company then it would have been.

"Find your companies' zen."